# I'm everything and everywhere

Tags: riddle

Usually I'm transparent, keep me clean.
Sometimes I'm generated by a fruit, keep me intact.
Sometimes I'm a penguin, keep me fresh.
Sometimes I'm in Star Trek, keep me in the future.
Sometimes I shine like the sun, keep me clear.
Rarely I'm something else.
And remember, you own me for sure!

**What am I?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Answer

> An operating system

### Reasoning

Usually I'm transparent, keep me clean.

> Windows, the most common operating system

Sometimes I'm generated by a fruit, keep me intact.

> MacOS or iOS, made by Apple

Sometimes I'm a penguin, keep me fresh.

> Linux, its symbol is a penguin

Sometimes I'm in Star Trek, keep me in the future.

> Android

Sometimes I shine like the sun, keep me clear.

> SunOS

Rarely I'm something else.

> Those are the most common operating systems.  Anything else is pretty rare.

And remember, you own me for sure!

> Anyone answering this question must own (or at least be using) an operating system of some sort.

Comment: Great job, and nice puzzle!

Comment: Actually, the star trek one was Android, but still an excellent answer, well done!